# Is there a notion of 'amenable ring'

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, amenability

Amenable groups are everywhere these days, as examples of all kinds of lovely phenomena. And there are various ways of defining notions of 'amenable monoid' or possibly 'amenable semigroup'. But for monoids and semigroups, amenability conditions that are known to be equivalent for groups are not always equivalent and there is a more complicated story unfolding. Nevertheless it seems natural to ask if there is a notion for rings.

Comment: There is a notion of amenable Banach Algebra https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_Banach_algebra. I'm not sure if it generalizes on a useful way to rings.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, see Elek, Gábor
The amenability of affine algebras. 
J. Algebra 264 (2003), no. 2, 469–478. 
and Gromov, Misha Entropy and isoperimetry for linear and non-linear group actions. Groups Geom. Dyn. 2 (2008), no. 4, 499-–593.

Comment: To be more precise, it's a notion of amenability for a $K$-algebra, $K$ being a field. Bartholdi proved that $G$ is amenable iff $KG$ is amenable. I don't know if the amenability of a $K$-algebra $A$ depends on $K$ (or only on the ground ring), nor if the definition extends to arbitrary (associative) rings.